# What is the correct way to trim a string to a certain amount of characters after a certain character?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempting to trim a string that is a number (ex. "123456.1234"). I want to trim it to only have two characters after the decimal (ex. "123456.12"). I've been trying this with substring but to no avail. What is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Example of what I'm working with where the_number_string is the string that needs trimmed.

```
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Text(
                                '\$${data.the_number_string}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            )
```

Comment: Why not use a number value and apply .toStringAsFixed(2), for example https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html ?

Comment: Mostly everything I'm working with requires strings unfortunately. Including coming in as strings and having to be strings to be sent off. So I'm trying to keep strings as strings where I can

Comment: So why not create a function that accepts a numeric string, converts it to a double, rounds to two decimal places, converts it back to a string and returns the string. Then you just call the function whenever you need to. Number processing is usually best done on numbers, not strings. You also need to decide if it should be trimmed or rounded. Can be important with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist on a String solution. First find the index of "." and then use substring. Please see the code below.

```
void main() {
    String abc = "123456.1234";
    print(abc.substring(0,abc.indexOf(".")+3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, though you should consider using double for such cases:

```
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            '\$${num.tryParse(data.the_number_string).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                        )
```